# Apache unable to write to files and folders on Fedora 16

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, fedora-16

I've recently installed Fedora 16 on a new PC, and I'm intending to use it for developing my websites. I've set up Apache to host multiple development sites on the machine.

Right now though, I am trying to install a PHP framework (Symfony2) and I'm unable to install it on to the web server. It comes back with an error saying that it's unable to write to the cache folder on the server.

I have checked and modified the folder so that it is writeable, but still the error keeps being displayed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the exact permissions on this folder? What exactly is Symfony saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues like these always seem to turn out to be SELinux. I'd try disabling it temporarily and see if that fixes it:
`sudo setenforce 0`

I personally leave SELinux off right now; I'm developing with an oracle DB in a php program, and SELinux is horrible with php-ociconnect. Oracle's recommended solution is actually to turn it off.  ociconnect has a similar issue to what you are having, exept for there's no errors during install, it just fails to install. It also won't start the module with it enabled when httpd is sta
Security-wise that's probably not good, but I just haven't had the time or the need to make oracle play nice with SElinux

Comment: SELinux annoys me at the best of times, and I've realised that I haven't turned it off like I usually do. I will do this later and report back.

Comment: I disabled SELinux but the issue is still occuring.

Comment: Te other thing to check that I always forget about with Apache, is to make sure the parent folders are readable to apache.

Comment: I have tried changing the owner/user to www-data, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: The parent folders as well? I'm not sure if they have to be r+x or just r to the apache user. They might have to be r+x. Try adding world r+x permissions all the way up to root. If that doesn't fix it, I have no idea what else to try. Check the access logs of linux, see what they say.